# Ufft example compilation

Tags: c, compilation, fft, vivado

I want to run the example project which is available for free from [this](http://www.fit.vutbr.cz/research/prod/?id=510) link. It is a simple FFT library and needs no compiler. In it, there is an example c file with its required header files and .c files.

When I try to run it in Vivado SDK I get errors of multiple definitions of fft and ifft. How can I run this example inside SDK?

What I had done is created an empty application project and then imported all these files inside src folder and then selected build the project option but didn't succeed in building and running the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, looking at the ufft.zip archive, that you've tried to link files issued form the compilation of `fft-dit.c` and `fft-dif.c`.

Both files define `ftt` functions using differents method (see `README`).

You have to choose betwen using `ftt-dif.c` or `ftt-dit.c`, not both.

This is the same for  `itt-dif.c` and `itt-dit.c`, choose one, not both.